# I just installed Quixel and Nuke, how can I create an alias for them in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

I just installed Quixel Bridge and Nuke. They are not found in the application list so I have no way to drag them to desktop favorite. Nor did they like Google Chrome that could be started in terminal by typing `google-chrome`. I could not figure out how to edit `~/.bashrc` to create an alias.

I tried

```
alias quixel="/usr/local/Bridge.AppImage"
```

and I put the above line into the `~/.bashrc` file, but it does not work.

How can I start those apps like `google-chrome`?

Comment: Did you try search your computer to find them?

Comment: How did you "installed Quixel Bridge and Nuke"? Are they both Appimages?